# PHP to Programatically delete a file

Tags: php

I am writing a plugin that allows the user to upload files to the upload directory of WordPress.

I want them to be able to "uninstall" the files with the click of a button. When the user clicks the button, I want the files to be deleted. I have successful been able to set up uploading and placing the files in the correct directory, but when it comes to deleting the files it is not working.

I am trying a very simple `unlink('file/path');` but it doesn't seem to be deleting my file.

```
<?php

$filename = 'direct/path/to/file/for/testing/purposes';
unlink($filename);

?>
```

It seems like the function is running when I click the button, but the file is never deleted. The path is correct as I've double checked it a few times. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please clarify how this question is **specific to WordPress**. As-written, it is a **PHP** question, merely in the *context* of WordPress.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833389/debugging-php-unlink-permissions-error

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using WordPress scheduled events.

Please take a look here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event